# Update content in a file being published using storage extension

Tags: 2011, storage-extensions

We are publishing an xml file from our CMS. We have to add some additional information in that xml file before it get deployed. I want to edit it in the storage extension. How can we achieve this?

In the XML file I want to add some xml nodes.

Comment: If you make your question more concrete, you will get more valuable answers - what information are you adding, and why do you want to add it in a storage extension, rather than at publish time?

Comment: How is the XML file generated and published, is it based on a Component or it is just a Page? And is there a hard requirement to update it in a Storage Extension, or could that also be done at Publish time in a Template for example?

Answer (score 6):

Once you have added the "additional information" using `Engine.PublishContext.RenderedItem.AddMetadata`, you can use a Deployer Extension. Here is an example (framework) to deal with Deployer Extensions:

[Custom Deployer Extensions Framework](http://jaimesantosalcon.blogspot.com/2013/10/sdl-tridion-custom-deployer-extension.html)

On a side note, if what you need to do is to add more nodes to your xml, you can do it in the template as well, not necessarily using the `.AddMetadata` method but modifying the `Output` instead. If this is something you need strictly to happen at deployment time, using the framework above, you can write your own `CustomAction` which gets the page  output (there's utils methods to access the `pages.xml` within the deployment package) and modify the xml (add more nodes) based on your requirements and then saves it back to the original xml file.

Answer (score 4):

You can add metadata to the rendered item, try the `Engine.PublishContext.RenderedItem.AddMetadata` method. all the metadata you add there can be accessed in the Storage Layer or Deployer Extension.

Comment: More info about AddMetadata and AddInstruction, here http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/10/rendereditem-metadata-and-instruction.html